# Email Already Registered Using Java Files

Tags: java, email

I am making a signup program. The details get stored in a text file. If the user enters an e-mail that is already taken, the message should be displayed as, "Email already registered". If it's not, then the e-mail should be written to a file. I have written the code but it always says that the email is already registered and writes nothing to the file. What's the problem here? I have to use files only and not arrays or Hashmaps. Here's my code, verification() is for verification of the e-mail format and duplicate() is to check the existence of email:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your e-mail");
        email = input.nextLine();
        check = validation(email);
        if (check == false) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid email");
        } else {
            check = duplicate(email);
            if (check == true) {
                writer.write("Email : " + email);
                writer.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("E-mail already registered");
            }
        }
    }
    while (check == false);
}

public static boolean validation(String email) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (email.contains("@")) {
        if (email.contains(".com")) {
            valid = true;
        }
    } else {
        valid = false;

    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic simply is reversed. `duplicate` returns `true` iff the email is already used. That means your check should be:

```
check=duplicate(email);
if (!check) {
    writer.write("Email : "+email);
    writer.println();
} else {
    System.out.println("E-mail already registered");
}
```

And you should give your variables and methods better names:

```
boolean isDuplicate = isMailAlreadyRegistered(email);
if (!isDuplicate) {
    writer.write("Email : "+email);
    writer.println();
} else {
    System.out.println("E-mail already registered");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was making such a silly mistake though.